# DataLouder in PyTorch / SpykeTorch: problem of transformed data extraction

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

Colleagues, I work with Neural Networks in PyTorch and SpykeTorch (based on PyTorch) and I need to create image datasets and place them in DataLouders for further processing.
The complete procedure is as follows:
1.generation of tensors,
2.transform them using torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage (),
3.saving the created images to a directory,
*4.creating an ImageFolder based on the directory with image transformation (using filters)*,
5.create DataLoader from ImageFolder.

```
image_set = torch.rand([10000, 28, 28], dtype=torch.float)   

path = './data/images/'  
os.makedirs(path)  
        
tTPI = torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()   
    
for i in range(n):   
    single_image = tTPI(image_set[i])     
    image_file = path+f'pic_{i}.jpg'   
    saved_image = single_image.save(f'{path}pic_{i}.jpg')    

kernels = [ SpykeTorch.utils.DoGKernel(7,1,2),
            SpykeTorch.utils.DoGKernel(7,2,1)]
filter = SpykeTorch.utils.Filter(kernels, padding = 3, thresholds = 50)
s1 = S1Transform(filter)

RandomImageFolder = ImageFolder(root='./data/', transform = s1)  
RandomDataLoader = DataLoader(RandomImageFolder, batch_size=len(RandomImageFolder))
```

Further, the data from the DataLoader is used in work (for example, it is recognized by the neural network).

```
for data, target in RandomDataLoader:
    prediction_X, prediction_y = predict(model, data, target)
```

The problem is, when pulling out data and labels from DataLoader, an error occurs:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups = 1, weight of size [2, 1, 7, 7], expected input [1, 3, 28, 28] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead
```

Judging by the dimension [1, 2, 7, 7], the error occurs at **stage 4**, where a set of filters is used for transformation.
However, using a different set of filters in such situations does not cause any error.
How can I solve the problem without changing the filters?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the generated * .jpg files, when loaded into ImageFolder, were perceived as RGB and had a size  [1, 3, 28, 28] instead of [1, 1, 28, 28].

I added in *transform*:

```
from PIL import ImageOps
 
gray_image = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
```